# I like NewYork, but I have never been there this year

Tags: grammar

I'm not a native speaker.
I have some question on the grammar of present perfect tense.
Is this sentence self-contradictory？

Comment: Please [edit] this. *What* is the sentence you're unclear about - the title? Then put that in the text with a > in front (quote).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't use **never** with a bounded time period such as **this year**.

We do use

- "... I have **not** been there this year" (typically means you have been there, just not this year)
- "... I have **never** been there"

We do use it with completely unbounded time (ever) or partially bound (before X/after X)

- "I have **never** been there **ever**" (emphatic)
- "I have **never** been there **before this year**" (but I went this year)
- "I have **never** been there **until this year**" (I went this year)
- "He **never** went there **after 1956** (implies he went before then)

This is standard English; note that non-standard variants vary in this matter.

Comment: Thank you very much！